# DotNetOpenAuth 4 Not Reading Config Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

How do I configure dotnetopenauth to not use a secure channel?  Below are my web config settings.  When I try to create WebServerClient with unsecured endponts, i get a message that HTTPS is required.  Am I missing something?  It seems like dotnetopenauth is not reading the config values.

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections> 

    <dotNetOpenAuth>
    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. -->
    <!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ -->
    <!-- You may also refer to README.Bin.html for instructions on enabling Intellisense for this section. -->
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <security requireSsl="false">
          <!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
          <trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="false">
            <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
            <add endpoint="http://localhost/oauth" />
          </trustedProviders>
        </security>
        <behaviors>
          <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
               with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
    </openid>
    <!-- Relaxing SSL requirements is useful for simple samples, but NOT a good idea in production. -->
    <messaging relaxSslRequirements="true">
      <untrustedWebRequest>
        <whitelistHosts>
          <!-- since this is a sample, and will often be used with localhost -->
          <add name="localhost" />
        </whitelistHosts>
      </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
    <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
    <reporting enabled="false" />
  </dotNetOpenAuth>
```

Comment: Please add the `<configSections>` element from your web.config file to your code snippet.

Comment: I added that section.  I was using the beta build 4.0.0.12030.  I down graded to 4.0.0.11165 and was able to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working on the newer build of DNOA because your `<configSections>` are out of date.  You can take a look at what it must look like for DNOA 4.0 [here](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/master/samples/OAuthClient/Web.config).

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
        <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
        <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
        <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
        <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```